# Weird rasterization artifacts

Tags: graphics, image, wolfram-cloud

When I try to rasterize circle with modified border thickness I get weird artifacts

```
Image[Graphics[{Thickness[.2],Circle[]}]]
```

[image]

Anyone knows any workaround how to get rid of those artifacts?

Note: This happens in Wolfram development platform (Online version of Mathematica). I haven't got a chance to find out how the code behaves in desktop version.

$Version 11.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2017)

Comment: The desktop version is fine, even on Linux (v11.0.1).  Please do mention the version of Mathematica (`$Version`). You might try `AbsoluteThickness` instead of `Thickness` and see if it still misbehaves.

Comment: I get the same results with `AbsoluteThickness`. Looks like a bug in online platform, I will report it.

Comment: It could be a bug in v11.1 for Linux. But that version is not yet released for the desktop. It is expected in a few days.

Comment: While I'm tempted to say you have accessed the [Arrival form](http://blog.wolfram.com/2017/01/31/analyzing-and-translating-an-alien-language-arrival-logograms-and-the-wolfram-language/) of Mathematica, sadly, it isn't so. Reported it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Should we tag this as a bug?

Comment: @Alexey Yes. I didn't do it because I don't know if it is a 11.1-bug, a 11.1 Linux bug, or something specific to the cloud. Once 11.1 is out, we'll know.

Comment: Just define `drawBomb[]:=Image[Graphics[{Thickness[1], Circle[]}]]` and we can call it feature: [Bomb image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bFcAZ.png)